# Excel - Filter Function - Exclude Range of Values

Tags: excel, function, performance, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have a range of data I need to filter but am wanting to filter out a specific range of values A2:Z2. As you can see, my formula references not including (<>) those values but the formula is very long (I shortened it down) and it is lagging my spreadsheet as I have to reuse this formula.

Can someone help me figure out how to exclude a range of data in the filter function without using Boolean * <> statements that can make this same idea more efficient.

Thank you!

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O,
('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M=C2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M<>"")*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$B$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$C$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$D$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$E$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$F$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$G$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$H$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$I$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$J$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$K$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$L$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$M$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$N$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$O$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$P$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$Q$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$R$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$S$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$T$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$U$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$V$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$W$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$X$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$Y$2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O<>'Org Chart'!$Z$2))),"")
```

Did an extensive search and have not found a solution that has helped me make this function more efficient.

Comment: Try: `=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O,
ISNA(XMATCH('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O,'Org Chart'!$B$2:$X$2))*
('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M=C2)*
('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M<>""),"")),"")`

Comment: Also, don't use pass entire columns to `FILTER`.

Comment: Wow! Your formula worked and at a much quicker speed. Thank you so much Mayukh! And thank you Jos! I am no longer searching full columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted above.

[image]

---

Try:

```
=IFERROR(UNIQUE(FILTER('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O, 
ISNA(XMATCH('Direct Report Data'!$O:$O,'Org Chart'!$B$2:$X$2))* 
('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M=C2)* ('Direct Report Data'!$M:$M<>""),"")),"")
```

---

Also as mentioned above by **[Jos Woolley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17007704/jos-woolley)** Sir, try to avoid using the whole range so that the blank rows are not taken into consideration which leads to slow down the working capability of Excel.